# Span word break on iOS7 webkit

Tags: html, ios, css, webkit, ios7

Today i upgrade my phone to iOS7 and find out some weird problem .

(blog.niwyclin.org)
This is a test post page of my web site

On desktop browser it looks fine.

I use Responsivator to check, and its perfect, like this (i.minus.com/ipy6XHEepJcvf.png)

but on browser in iOS7 (include safari and chrome)

(i.minus.com/i2B2Ul5f09WL8.png)

(i.minus.com/iDM5uVFIvegKe.png)

it break a word but i don't know why.

It has `white-space: pre` set.

Any issues with the my css(less) code?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution.

From http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

it seems webkit on iOS 7 changes `overflow-wrap` property.

so i add `pre {overflow-wrap: normal;}` manuale, and it's done.